# How to jump to same function again after exception in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have below script which generates report for large size data.
Due to large size data request call times out.
I have added exception to handle this situation which works fine to get keep script running.
Issue I am having is after exception it goes to next project and skips the projects where it timed out.
I want it to start from same project again.
How can I achieve this ?

```
if __name__ = ‘__main__’
for project in AllProjectData['value']:
    try:
        project_name   = project['name']
        ** code to be executed 
    except:
        requests.ConnectionError,
        requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout,
        requests.exceptions.Timeout,
        requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout
        continue
```

Comment: Write a function for this so that when except statement is run, you can call it

Comment: Can you please explain more on this ?

Comment: Ok i will answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are catching exceptions in a very odd way. I've never seen it done like this. I believe this code is catching **all** exceptions. For example:

```
try:
    1/0
except:
    ZeroDivisionError
    pass
```

Works fine, but so does (it should raise `IndexError`):

```
try:
    a = []
    print(a[1])
except:
    ZeroDivisionError
    pass
```

So you shouldn't write `except` statements this way. What you should have is something along the lines:

```
success = False
while not success:
    try:
        # Your execution code
    except (requests.ConnectionError,
            requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout,
            requests.exceptions.Timeout,
            requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout):
        continue
    else:
        success = True
```

Also you should try and not put so much code in your `except` statement as it is confusing as to what you're trying to catch and where. Also, you're completely missing some possibilities like a `KeyError` when there's no `id` field in `project` and others.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
def myfunc():
    # Write the code given in question completely

    # Then add this in your except statement
    except:
        requests.ConnectionError,
        requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout,
        requests.exceptions.Timeout,
        requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout

        # Call your function so that it will jump back to the same function
        myfunc()
        
        # You don't need continue keyword because it jumps to the same function
```

Comment: You should guard this with a counter, otherwise you could easily run into infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use a while loop with a counter variable. Let me demonstrate:

```
i = 0
while i < len(AllProjectData['value']):
    try:
        project = AllProjectData['value'][i]
        # code to be executed
        i += 1 # increment counter on success
    except:
        requests.ConnectionError,
        requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout,
        requests.exceptions.Timeout,
        requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout
        continue
```

This way, you will go to the next project only if work on the previous project was executed, as the loop variable is incremented only in the `try` block.

Note: I have assumed that your iterable is indexable. If it's not, just pass it inside the `list()` constructor.

Comment: I tried this but it works on starting again from same project but it’s going in never ending loop.

Comment: @megha That means you are always running into a timeout, so you can have another counter to specify how many times to try before giving up and proceeding to the next one.